# Crystal Report hide main report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010, subreport

I am using Crystal report to display my reports. I have one report which is containing sub report also. Now I want to show only sub report and hide main report in some situation. Can it be possible that hide main report and display sub report only.

Can anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

leave the section where sub report is placed and for rest all sections apply supress property.... you can directly use supress or you can also conditionally supress by writing a formula by going to section expert.